# How to link the site URL from 'posted XX minutes ago via APPNAME'

Tags: android, facebook, url, hyperlink, deep-linking

I have integrated facebook to my android App, and posting through the App. On below posted photo by my application I see "posted XX minutes ago via APPNAME",  clicking 'APPNAME' no reaction. How can I change this link to my google play for example.

So how for example instagram or other apps redirect "via app" to their sites ?

I want my app to be able to make a share on Facebook which will appear as a link via my page. 
Is it possible?

I used to facebook sdk v2.0 and referenced below site.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/
I've set the below information . 
Settings -> Basic -> app -> Website with Facebook Login, Mobile Web, Native Android App.

But, page didn't redirect in case of Native Android Facebook app.
I can't link To my native App.